# C++ Create Triangles with For Loops

Tags: c++, for-loop, output

I have a problem.

I used the for loops but I couldn't solve this problem.

But I created only 2 triangle on left side. How can I create right side triangles symetrical?

Here, it's my code:

```
int main()
{
    int uzunluk = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < uzunluk; j++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout <<  endl;
        uzunluk--;
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= uzunluk; j++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
        uzunluk++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to output spaces between the triangles:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  const int size = 6;
  int uzunluk = size;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < uzunluk; j++) {
      cout << "*";
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < (size - uzunluk + 1) * 2; j++){
      cout << " ";
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < uzunluk; j++) {
      cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
    uzunluk--;
  }

  cout << endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j <= uzunluk; j++) {
      cout << "*";
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < (size - uzunluk) * 2; j++){
      cout << " ";
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= uzunluk; j++) {
      cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
    uzunluk++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment and help. I fixed the problem.

Comment: I fixed this problem but i have  one more question. Why did you use uzunluk and size? Why didn't use only uzunluk variable?

Comment: @M.Bugra Because `uzunluk` changes, but you need to keep the original value (in `size`)

Comment: Thank you. I get it finally

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
    for (int j = uzunluk; j < 5; j++)
    {
       cout << " ";
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < uzunluk; j++)
    {
       cout << "*";
    }
    cout <<  endl;
    uzunluk--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

  void main()
{
     int i,n,j,x;
      clrscr();
      printf("\n ENTER A VALUE: ");
      scanf("%d",&i);
      for(n=i;n>0;n--)
      {
          for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
          printf(" * ");
          for(j=i-n;j>=1;j--)
          printf("      ");
          for(x=n;x>=1;x--)
          printf(" * ");
          printf("\n");
      }
     for(n=0;n<i;n++)
     {
         for(j=0;j<=n;j++)
         printf(" * ");
         for(j=i-n;j>=2;j--)
         printf("      ");
         for(x=n;x>=0;x--)
         printf(" * ");
         printf("\n");
     }
         getch();
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following code and modify it for your purposes. However, it is also good to practice with formatting functions, such as `setw` of outputstream.

```
int main()
{
    const int Length = 10;
    const int Height=5;
    std::string gap;

    for (int i = 0; i < Height; i++) 
    {

        for (int j = i; j < Length-i; j++)
        {

            cout << "*";


        }
        cout <<  endl;
        gap=gap+' ';
        cout<<gap;
    }



 }
```